# Is it natural to say "squeeze the toy chick to make it hiss" and "shake the toy chick to make it flash"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

I have a tiny rubber toy chick like the above picture.

When I squeeze it, it makes some hissing sound.

When I shake it, it flashes or blinks

Is it natural to say "**squeeze the toy chick to make it hiss**" and "**shake the toy chick to make it flash**"?

Comment: I imagine you know that's a bath toy, and when used as such it **squirts** water. But sure, when used dry, it might make a hissing sound. Similar toys for pets are called **squeaky toys**.

Comment: @TypeIA, so we say "squeeze it to make it squeaky"?

Comment: No, squeaky is an adjective. The verb and noun are both squeak, and it's a different sound than a hiss. Squeaky toys squeak; your bath toy may squeak or hiss when used dry, or squirt when used with water.

Comment: @TypeIA, I might have understood the sound of the above toy wrongly. I would say the toy makes both squeak and hissing sound all together. If it made only hissing sound, people wouldn't buy it.

Comment: @Tom  sounds to me like it has a defect - not surprising in what is clearly a very cheap item.  But back to the question - both examples are fine to my eyes.

Comment: @Tom Not at all. My kids have bath toys almost identical to the one in your picture. They don't squeak, they hiss. The purpose of the toy isn't really to make sound, but to draw in and squirt out water from the bathtub. (This is different from the purpose of a squeaky toy for pets, which presumably squeak to amuse the animal and annoy its owners!)

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, both are correct.

In general, "X the Y to make it Z", where X is a verb, Y is a noun, and Z is another verb, is correct6 and natural. This is in the imperitive mood, and is instructional. The speaker is telling someone what  to do (X) to achieve a result (Z).